# Can not return a value to the screen from method in Scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I need to display to the screen some values which are read in method defined in the script-let. The code below does not compiles:

```
<%!
    void displayRecursively(KnowledgeElement ke, ExtendsRelationshipService ers){
        List<ExtendsRelationship> erList = null;
        %><%=ke.getName()%><br /><%!
        try {
            erList = ers.findIncomingExtendsKERelationships(ke);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        if (erList!=null){
            for (ExtendsRelationship er : erList){
                KnowledgeElement startKe = er.getStartKE();
                displayRecursively(startKe,ers);
            }
        }
    } 
%>  

<%
    KnowledgeElement ke = null;
    ke = (KnowledgeElement)request.getAttribute("knowledgeElement");
    ExtendsRelationshipService ers = (ExtendsRelationshipService)request.getAttribute("ers");
    displayRecursively(ke,ers);             
%>
```

The compilation error is:

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ke
  location: class org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.ke_jsp
```

With .. %><%=ke.getName()%><% .. does not compiles as well.
Can someone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Move your code to a servlet. Using scriptlets is bad practice. JSP is for view purposes not to generate code.

Comment: Cant find any suitable from JSTL side to handle this. As you might see, I want to display a Tree structure here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet containers compile JSP code into servlet classes following this approach:

- When using the "<%! ... %>" scriptlet symbols you are defining code that is going to be part of the servlet class itself, which allows you to define functions.
- When using the "<% ... %>" scriptlet symbols you are defining code that is going to be part of the "service" method of the servlet itself.

So, what you are doing is mixing code that is being declared outside the "service" method with a reference to variable that is going to be copied inside the "service" method.

To solve your problem I would add another parameter to your function and replace that "cross-reference" (or whatever it should be called). It would look like this:

```
<%!
    void displayRecursively(JspWriter out, KnowledgeElement ke, ExtendsRelationshipService ers){
        List<ExtendsRelationship> erList = null;
        out.print(ke.getName());
        out.println("<br />");
        try {
            erList = ers.findIncomingExtendsKERelationships(ke);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        if (erList!=null){
            for (ExtendsRelationship er : erList){
                KnowledgeElement startKe = er.getStartKE();
                displayRecursively(out, startKe,ers);
            }
        }
    } 
  %>
```

When invoking that function in your other scriptlet you must past in the reference to the PrintWriter (which is an implicit variable for scriptlets that go inside the "service" method):

```
displayRecursively(out, ke, era);
```

Just notice that you will need page import of the "JspWriter" class in your JSP in order to compile.

Comment: out is not a PrintWriter. It is a javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter  .

Answer (score 1):

As the JSP style guide [noted nearly a decade](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) ago:

> Where possible, avoid JSP scriptlets whenever tag libraries provide equivalent functionality. This makes pages easier to read and maintain, helps to separate business logic from presentation logic, and will make your pages easier to evolve into JSP 2.0-style pages...

Recursion with templates is tricky, but it can be done.

Here is a presentation-tier object that adapts your objects to something that can be consumed by EL, can handle exceptions, etc:

```
public class RelationshipPresentation {
  private final ExtendsRelationshipService service;
  private final ExtendsRelationship relationship;

  public RelationshipPresentation(ExtendsRelationshipService service, 
                                  ExtendsRelationship relationship) {
    this.service = service;
    this.relationship = relationship;
  }

  public String getName() { return relationship.getName(); }

  public List<RelationshipPresentation> getRelated() {
    List<RelationshipPresentation> list =
                                   new ArrayList<RelationshipPresentation>();
    try {
      for (ExtendsRelationship er :
           service.findIncomingExtendsKERelationships(relationship)) {
        list.add(new RelationshipPresentation(service, er));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) { /*Catching Exception?!*/ }
      return list;
  }
}
```

It is also easy to unit-test this type in isolation to your markup.

This is placed into scope prior to dispatching to the JSP:

```
RelationshipPresentation relationshipPresentation =
                         new RelationshipPresentation(ers, knowledgeElement);
request.setAttribute("relationshipPresentation", relationshipPresentation);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ercontainer.jsp")
                   .forward(request, response);
```

Here is a JSP fragment (`er.jsp`) that displays the names in un-ordered lists:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:out value="${relationshipPresentation.name}" />
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="relationshipPresentation"
               items="${relationshipPresentation.related}">
        <c:set var="relationshipPresentation"
               value="${relationshipPresentation}" scope="request"/>
        <li><jsp:include page="er.jsp"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

This can be included in your main page with the JSP action `<jsp:include page="er.jsp" />`.

Answer (score 0):

<%!..%> is called declarative tag. You can use the variables declared and methods defined under declarative tag in service(<%..%>), but not the parameter of a method from declarative tag.